# Older than remote repository but 2022 had been installed and now need to update packages

Tags: tlmgr, update

I had installed TeX Live 2022 on Debian 11 with

```
cd /tmp # working directory of your choice
wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz # or curl instead of wget
zcat install-tl-unx.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd install-tl-*
perl ./install-tl --no-interaction # as root or with writable destination
Finally, prepend /usr/local/texlive/YYYY/bin/PLATFORM to your PATH,
e.g., /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Now I need to update packages and install new packages that I hadn't installed, so I input:

```
tlmgr update --all
```

and see

> tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2022).
> Cross release updates are only supported with
> update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See
> https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

It is weird as there is no TeX Live (2020) on my Debian 11. Then I tried:

```
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
```

There is an error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.sh/.exe'

How shoud I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe `which tlmgr` will tell you some info? // When I use `tlmgr` on Ubuntu, I cannot use `sudo tmlgr`, and have to use the absolute of `tlmgr` with `sudo`.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Hello. `which tlmgr` shows `/usr/bin/tlmgr`. I input the absolute of `tlmgr` with `sudo` but it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the syntax error from bash: the round brackets/parentheses show options you can use, and shouldn't be typed directly. If you are on Windows, use `update-tlmgr-latest.exe --update`, if you are on Linux or similar (which you are, since you use Debian), use `update-tlmgr-latest.sh --update`. Read below before you do that, since the error you got indicates some sort of problem.

Given you have installed TeX Live on Debian, you might be running into the problem that there are two versions of TeX Live installed: one from you installing TeX Live 2022, and one installed using the Debian package manager as a dependency for something (which is likely to be older, due to the way Debian packages software). As a result, typing `tlmgr` may be invoking the wrong one (the Debian installed one, which appears to be TeX Live 2020).

There are instructions to integrate TeX Live with Debian on the [TUG Website](https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html), but if you have already installed TL via Debian's package manager, you may not be able to clean it well enough (I don't have enough experience with removing packages from Debian to describe any consequences you may have).

On your problem, though, try `locate tlmgr` and see if there is more than one present. If so, use the full path to the 2022 version to update that install. The comment from Teddy van Jerry suggests using `which tlmgr`, which will point to the version which is run if you just type `tlmgr` without a path, so that may also give you information about why you are having problems.

---

From the comments, below:

`tlmgr` refers to `/usr/bin/tlmgr`, which is a symlink to `../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl` . This means that there is a TeX Live distribution installed by Debian's package manager.

Rather than delete this manually, or even removing the packages, the issues can be resolved by changing the `PATH` environment variable of the user. By putting the path to your (manually installed) TeX Live 2022 bin directory at the start of your path, the whole system should work without issue. I'm not sure where you installed TeX Live 2022, but if you installed it in `/usr/local/texlive/2022`, add `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux` to your `PATH` variable.

To update the `PATH` for your user, edit your user's `.bashrc` file to add a line like this somewhere near the bottom: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}` and save the file. Start a new shell, and run `which tlmgr` - it should print out `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr` (not `/usr/bin/tlmgr`). If so, you can then use `tlmgr update --all` to upgrade. Make sure when you edit your `.bashrc` file that you use the path to the TeX Live you installed, where ever that is. You may also need to do this for `root`'s `.bashrc` file, if you use `sudo tlmgr` to update.

Comment: After entering `which tlmgr`, there is only one line of `/usr/bin/tlmgr`. And `locate tlmgr` exports all the lines of `texlive/2022`, so I can't see there is **texlive** about 2020. Maybe there isn't **texlive of 2020**.

Comment: @Y.zeng On an install I have here, `/usr/bin/tlmgr` is a symlink, and I assume yours is as well. What is the output from running `ls -l /usr/bin/tlmgr` ? That will tell you what file is actually being run when you call `tlmgr`.

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Feb 17  2021 /usr/bin/tlmgr -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl`. So, should I delete the folder of **../share/texlive** and make `/usr/bin/tlmgr` point to **texlive 2022**?

Comment: @Y.zeng, I have updated my answer to take into account the information you have provided in the comments, here

Comment: But I needn't to keep folder of **../share/texlive**, as it is too old and the 2022 version had been installed, so shoudn't I delete it?

Comment: Alter having edited the **.bashrc** files on every account and **root**. When run `which tlmgr`, it outputs `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, but when run `sudo tlmgr update --all`, it still outputs `tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2022).`.  When run `ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, it outputs `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Oct  3  2018 /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr -> ../../texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl`.

Comment: @Y.zeng You shouldn't delete the `../share/texlive` manually, as it has been installed by the package manager. If you do want to delete it, use the package manager to remove the package which provides it (you may not be able to, since there may be other packages which have it as a dependency). If you are having trouble with the paths, you should be able to run `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all`, which should run the correct version, and have no problems.

Comment: I have sereval questions. 1. Now, `tlmgr` point to `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, so what is the difference between `sudo tlmgr update --all` and `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all`? 2. How should I remove texlive 2020 but not affect the texlive 2022? 3. When I run `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all`, will it download the packages those I hadn't downloaded? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142477/discussion-between-enkorvaks-and-y-zeng).

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer specifically for MacOS. But solution 2 probably applies to other OSes as well. Note that on MacOS, TeX Live is usually installed through the [MacTeX distribution](https://tug.org/mactex/), but it is essentially the same thing.

When trying to update packages (or the package manager itself), I received the error message mentioned in the OP question:

```bash
sudo tlmgr update --self
# ...
# tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2022) is older than remote repository (2023).
# Cross release updates are only supported with
#   update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
# See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

**Solution 1**: To recover from this problem **without** upgrading the entire TeX Live distribution (e.g., from 2022 to 2023), the following worked for me:

- Open the TeX Live Utility. It is distributed alongside TeX Live and usually resides under /Applications/TeX/
- Under Actions, choose Reinstall TeX Live Manager.

**Solution 2**: As described in the section "Distaster recovery" of the [tlmgr documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html), it is recommended to use `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`. The script is available on this website. I have not tested this solution myself, but I suspect that this is what Tex Live Manager ends up using to fix the problem in Solution 1.